# Deploying ElasticSearch on Heroku without Re(Tire), but with Elasticsearch-Rails & Bonsai.io

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, tire

Tire has Re(tire)d, but all tutorials still explain how to set up Elasticsearch with Bonsai on Heroku using Tire.

I would like to make it working with Elastic 1.0.1 and above.

Just deploying it on Heroku , I get that in the heroku logs:

```
2014-04-02T08:11:46.989615+00:00 app[web.1]: Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200):
```

It is not set up with the Bonsai account that is set up on my heroku page https://[MYID:-)]:[MYID:-)]@cherry-5964158.us-east-1.bonsai.io/

Locally, I get Elasticsearch up and running.

What do I have to do?

Comment: UPDATE: I switched from tire to searchkick.
And used searchbox instead of bonsai on heroku.
now, it works... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would help anyone:

It seems like that the connection setting is wrong. If you check the Bonsai on Heroku documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai#connection-refused, there are two ways to config that:

1. using the gem:

`gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails'`

1. manually setting it:

`Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['BONSAI_URL']`

The BONSAI_URL can be found using the dashboard: `heroku addons:open bonsai`

Hope this helps.